# Delete records in a text file based on column number and condition - python

Tags: python, list, text

I need to delete records from a text file in python based on a condition being met.
This is a sample of the text file:

```
xxxxxxx 0 5 zzzz
yyyyyyy 1 7 tttt
ggggggg 0 5 dddd
fffffff 1 5 gggg
```

I need to delete all rows except those which contain 0 in the second column, so that it will display the following:

```
xxxxxxx 0 5 zzzz
ggggggg 0 5 dddd
```

So far I only managed to work out a code that only DISPLAYS this desired output but not actually deleting it from the text file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your rows, filter them and keep them in a `list`, then write them back again in the same file

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("file.txt")
rows = path.read_text().splitlines()

keep_rows = [row for row in rows if row.split()[1] == '0']
path.write_text("\n".join(keep_rows))
```